# How to format Ragged Tensor for Encoder-Decoder model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I'm working on building a **seq2seq** model using encoder-decoder architecture for which I have built a `tf.data.Dataset` pipeline that reads the text from the directories, vectorizes using them `tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization` and preprocess it to be fed for model training. I'm not able to format my `labels` such that it is of the shape `(None, seq_len, target_vocab_size)`. I tried using to map `tf.utils.to_categorical` to the labels but it won't work on the tensors. Strangely there is no material out there where there was a similar problem discussed. Below is my implementation:

```
BUFFER_SIZE = len(articles)
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_raw = (tf.data.Dataset
             .from_tensor_slices((articles[is_train], summaries[is_train]))
             .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
             .batch(BATCH_SIZE))

val_raw = (tf.data.Dataset
           .from_tensor_slices((articles[~is_train], summaries[~is_train]))
           .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
           .batch(BATCH_SIZE))

context_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize = tf_lower_and_split_punct,
    max_tokens = MAX_VOCAB_SIZE,
    ragged=True)

target_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=tf_lower_and_split_punct,
    max_tokens=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE,
    ragged=True)

context_vectorizer.adapt(train_raw.map(lambda context, target: context))
target_vectorizer.adapt(train_raw.map(lambda context, target: target))

def preprocess_text(context, target):
    context = context_vectorizer(context).to_tensor()
    target = target_vectorizer(target)

    target_in = target[:,:-1].to_tensor()
    target_out = target[:,1:].to_tensor()
    # target_out = target[:,:-1]
    return (context, target_in), target_out

train_ds = train_raw.map(preprocess_text, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_raw.map(preprocess_text, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

def encoder(hsize, embed_dim=200):
    en_input_layer = Input(shape=(None,), name='encoder_input_layer', ragged=True)
    en_embed = Embedding(context_vectorizer.vocabulary_size()+1, output_dim=embed_dim, name='encoder_embedding_layer')
    en_embed_out = en_embed(en_input_layer)
    en_gru_1 = GRU(hsize, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='encoder_gru_layer_1')
    en_gru_1_out, en_gru_states = en_gru_1(en_embed_out)
    return en_input_layer, en_gru_1_out, en_gru_states

def decoder(hsize, encoder_states, embed_dim=200):
    de_input_layer = Input(shape=(None,), name='decoder_input_layer', ragged=True)
    de_embed = Embedding(target_vectorizer.vocabulary_size()+1, output_dim=embed_dim, name='decode_embedding_layer')
    de_embed_out = de_embed(de_input_layer)
    de_gru_1 = GRU(hsize, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_gru_layer_1')
    de_gru_1_out = de_gru_1(de_embed_out, initial_state=encoder_states)
    de_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(target_vectorizer.vocabulary_size(), activation='softmax'), name='time_distributed_output_layer')
    de_preds = de_dense(de_gru_1_out)
    return de_input_layer, de_preds

hsize = 256

def create_model(hsize):
    en_input_layer, enc_out, enc_states = encoder(hsize)
    de_input_layer, de_preds = decoder(hsize, enc_states)
    model = Model(inputs=[en_input_layer, de_input_layer], outputs=de_preds)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=["acc"])
    return model

### Model training

m = create_model(hsize)

history = m.fit(
        train_ds.repeat(),
        steps_per_epoch=100,
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        callbacks=[
            tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('./checkpoints_trial_1',
                                                save_weights_only=True),
            tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3)])
```

**The model summary is below:**

---

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 encoder_input_layer (Input  [(None, None)]               0         []                            
 Layer)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 decoder_input_layer (Input  [(None, None)]               0         []                            
 Layer)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 encoder_embedding_layer (E  (None, None, 200)            437200    ['encoder_input_layer[0][0]'] 
 mbedding)                                                                                        
                                                                                                  
 decode_embedding_layer (Em  (None, None, 200)            244200    ['decoder_input_layer[0][0]'] 
 bedding)                                                                                         
                                                                                                  
 encoder_gru_layer_1 (GRU)   [(None, None, 256),          351744    ['encoder_embedding_layer[0][0
                              (None, 256)]                          ]']                           
                                                                                                  
 decoder_gru_layer_1 (GRU)   (None, None, 256)            351744    ['decode_embedding_layer[0][0]
                                                                    ',                            
                                                                     'encoder_gru_layer_1[0][1]'] 
                                                                                                  
 time_distributed_output_la  (None, None, 1220)           313540    ['decoder_gru_layer_1[0][0]'] 
 yer (TimeDistributed)                                                                            
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1698428 (6.48 MB)
Trainable params: 1698428 (6.48 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The model compile's fine but when I run the `fit` method I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, None, 1220) are incompatible
```

I'm struggling with defining the model's `Input` layers correctly, or `preprocess_text` output that would work with the model definition.

Comment: Try, (1):  `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.  or, (2). `target_out = tf.one_hot(target_out, depth=tf.cast(target_vectorizer.vocabulary_size(), dtype='int32'))` - Otherwise, please share colab gist to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Innat - You're a hero! Changing loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` worked like a charm. It's much more efficient than formatting the labels to `one_hot`. Thank you very much. Maybe you want to put just `compile` code in the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting from above comment, to fix the above issue, we can either **change the loss method** that works on **sparse vector** or **transform the target label to one-hot encoded**. Below is the complete working code with some dummy data.

```
make_one_hot = False # params: True, False

num_articles = 1000
num_summaries = 1000
MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 5000
articles = np.array([f"Article {i}" for i in range(num_articles)])
summaries = np.array([f"Summary {i}" for i in range(num_summaries)])
is_train = np.random.rand(len(articles)) < 0.8

def tf_lower_and_split_punct(text):
    text = tf.strings.lower(text)
    text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '[.?!,¿]', ' ')
    text = tf.strings.strip(text)
    text = tf.strings.join([' ', text, ' '])
    return text
```

```py
BUFFER_SIZE = len(articles)
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_raw = (tf.data.Dataset
             .from_tensor_slices((articles[is_train], summaries[is_train]))
             .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
             .batch(BATCH_SIZE))

val_raw = (tf.data.Dataset
           .from_tensor_slices((articles[~is_train], summaries[~is_train]))
           .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
           .batch(BATCH_SIZE))

context_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize = tf_lower_and_split_punct,
    max_tokens = MAX_VOCAB_SIZE,
    ragged=True)

target_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=tf_lower_and_split_punct,
    max_tokens=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE,
    ragged=True)

context_vectorizer.adapt(train_raw.map(lambda context, target: context))
target_vectorizer.adapt(train_raw.map(lambda context, target: target))
```

```
def preprocess_text(context, target):
    context = context_vectorizer(context).to_tensor()
    target = target_vectorizer(target)

    target_in = target[:,:-1].to_tensor()
    target_out = target[:,1:].to_tensor()
    
    if make_one_hot:
        target_out = tf.one_hot(
            target_out, 
            depth=tf.cast(
                target_vectorizer.vocabulary_size(), dtype='int32'
            )
        )
    return (context, target_in), target_out

train_ds = train_raw.map(preprocess_text, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_raw.map(preprocess_text, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

```py
def create_model(hsize):
    en_input_layer, enc_out, enc_states = encoder(hsize)
    de_input_layer, de_preds = decoder(hsize, enc_states)
    model = Model(inputs=[en_input_layer, de_input_layer], outputs=de_preds)
    
    if make_one_hot:
        loss_fn = 'categorical_crossentropy'
    else:
        loss_fn = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
    
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam', 
        loss=loss_fn,
        metrics=["acc"]
    )
    return model


model.fit(train_ds)
5s 24ms/step - loss: 6.7114 - acc: 0.003
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7bfef0423f40>
```

---

**Reference**

[Selecting loss and metrics for Tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848962/selecting-loss-and-metrics-for-tensorflow-model/67851641#67851641)

Comment: Hi @Innat, I'm trying to train the model but I keep getting a warning saying `WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 20 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.` Any idea why is that? I'll edit the question to add the `fit` code

Comment: yes, I've. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729070/9215780) post. To understand the `repeat`, along with the official [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat), you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517848/9215780) post also. If anyone of this doesn't help, please post your **new question** as it doesn't related to this one.